# Invoking .apply on .concat of array

Tags: javascript, variadic-functions

I'm creating wrappers for common JavaScript types that offer more features. In addition to new methods and properties, they have all of the same methods and properties as the types that they are wrappers for. I'm not completely rewriting the already existing methods even though I might change their logic, so I'm always calling back to the original method on the wrapped value.

Here is what `charCodeAt` might look like for a wrapper around strings:

```
this.charCodeAt = function (index) {
    return internalValue.charCodeAt(index);
};
```

I don't need to do much in the above example:

- The parameter `index` in a call to `string.charCodeAt` is optional, so I don't need to write any logic that would handle the case of the same parameter being omitted in a call to `wrapper.charCodeAt`.
- `index` is the only parameter `string.charCodeAt` takes, so there is also no need to handle additional variables passed to `wrapper.charCodeAt` as they will be ignored.

I've encountered a problem while trying to make calls to a method that accepts a variable number of arguments. The method in question is `array.concat`. There are other contexts in which I've written code to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to an function in JavaScript and the solution I've used is `func.apply(null, argumentArray)` where `argumentArray` is an array of the arguments I want to pass to `func`. This doesn't work for `.concat`:

```
var array = [0, 1];
var error;

try {
    array.concat.apply(null, [2, 3]);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

The error message that gets written to the console says `TypeError: Array.prototype.concat called on null or undefined`. I researched using `apply` with `concat` and it seems like I'd get similar problems with other methods that are defined on a constructor's prototype.

Why am I encountering this problem with `array.concat.apply`? What is the correct way to pass an arbitrary number of arguments as an array to a method such as `.concat`?

Answer (score 1):

Calling the prototype method and correctly setting the `this` argument in the call to `apply()` should work:

```js
var array = [0, 1];
var error;

try {
    array = Array.prototype.concat.apply(array, [2, 3]);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` expects a `this` value of an array (or array-like) object. When you do

```
array.concat.apply(null, [2, 3]);
```

the `this` value is `null`; it's effectively the same thing as

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply(null, [2, 3]);
```

Any reference to the original `array` is disregarded.

If you wanted to output the `concat` of the original array with `[2, 3]`, you would need to specify that the `this` value should be `array`:

```js
var array = [0, 1];
var arrayToConcat = [2, 3];
const result = array.concat.apply(array, arrayToConcat);
console.log(result);

// or, use array spread:
const result2 = [...array, ...arrayToConcat];
console.log(result2);

// or, use concat without anything special at all:
const result3 = array.concat(arrayToConcat);
console.log(result3);
```

(technically, you *can* use a non-array-like object as the `this` for `concat`, but it's an odd thing to do)

Comment: Why the need of the spread operator on `result2`, any reason for that?, it work without it...

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right. (though, since that's the case, can't you just `array.concat(arrayToConcat)`?)

Comment: I'm going to give another read to the OP Question, because I think I'm missing some point of why you have proposed `array.concat(...arrayToConcat)` and not `array.concat(arrayToConcat)`.

Comment: Like I said, you're right, there's no point in spreading there, but I'm confused as to why anything special is necessary, since `.concat(arrayToConcat)` appears to achieve the desired result.